# Calling to div inside div inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

```
function paintOrders(DivId) {
    var container = '<div>';
    $.each(DivId, function () {
        container += 'TXT' + '<br/><br/>';
    });
    container += '</div>';
    $('#div_' + DivId).append(container);
}
```

`ShipmentNum` is unique id
**the divs that I need to append the text into them are in another div and another div:**

```
<div id="leftGrid" style="position: relative;float:left;width:50%;">
<div>
<div id="div_11626">11626----</div>
<br>
<div id="div_12109">12109----0</div>
<br>
<div id="div_13089">13089----</div>
<br>
</div>
</div>


$('#div_' + items).append(container);
```

> ERROR uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
> [object Object]

Calling function:

```
function paintShipments(items) {
 var div = $('<div/>');
 $.each(items, function () {
     var shipment = this.Shipment;
     $('<div id="div_' + this.Shipment + '">' + this.Shipment + '----' + this.DriverNames + '---' + this.Kavs + '</div>').click(function () {
        

         _Services.invoke({
             method: 'GetOrdersGrid',
             data: { ShipmentNumber: shipment },
             success: function (shipment) {
                 paintOrders(shipment);
              
             }
         });


         }).appendTo(div);
         $('<br/>').appendTo(div);
     });

     $("#leftGrid").append(div);
 }
```

Comment: Are you calling your `paintOrders` function anywhere? If so, what value are you passing for the `DivId` parameter?

Comment: I added the calling function to the question

Comment: in the success method in .invoke(), your parameter is named shipment, yet you have a variable in the outer scope also named shipment. that's a bit vague - might it be a source of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any error.

http://jsbin.com/ugojiy/3/edit

What's your jQuery version?
Is there any other Javascript code error that it is interfering?